# How to convert the format of a cell from text to number when using forms to input data

Tags: forms, excel, vba

I am creating a form to enter data into my excel sheet. The problem I keep running into is that the information being entered is a number, but when running the VBA code for the form "save" button, the data I enter into the form is being put into the Excel sheet as text. This is causing the formula at the end of the row to not register the data (a simple `=sum(...)` formula). I have tried a few different options and have searched around for a solution but all of the answers that come close are for importing data from an external source.

This is the code for a single cell that will receive data from the form. There will be a lot more, but I think this will provide enough info. There is really little else in the code except that the `range("").select` changes and then data is pulled from a different text box in each new selection.

```
Private Sub butSaveData_Click()

    Sheet1.Activate

    Range("g8").Select
        ActiveCell.Value = txtAARs
        Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
```

I thought the `selection.numberformat` would resolve the issue but it persists. I changed the format in the Excel sheet, but when the form populates the cells, it continues to revert them back to text.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I searched this site quite a bit and could not find the answer. I hope I didn't miss it.

Comment: You should use `With Sheet1.Range("G8")
    .Value = var1
    .NumberFormat = "0.00"
End With` instead of a selection. I tried this code and the sum() worked even if the input var was declared as a string. the error has to come from something else in your code or fomating.

Comment: Try `Application.Calculate` after the text has been changed or calculate the sum in the vba code with `Sheet1.Range("H9").Value = Application.Sum(Range("H8:G8"))`

Comment: I tried your first suggestion, but it does nothing to change the format back to number. Likely, it is as you said, something is wrong in the excel formatting.

Comment: What is a sample of the value you have in `txtAARs`?

Comment: @YowE3K, it's just a whole number such as 4.

Comment: Very strange - I just tried your code (using values like "123") and it successfully placed a number into the cell.

Comment: @BombSquad my first suggestion was just how you should write your code, it is meant to do exactly the same.

Comment: No - it didn't - I automatically typed the equivalent of `txtAARs.Value` - without the `.Value` it places it into the cell as text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `txtAARs` is a `TextBox`, specify the `.Value` property.

```
Private Sub butSaveData_Click()

    Sheet1.Activate

    Range("g8").Select
        ActiveCell.Value = txtAARs.Value
        Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
```

---

Refactored to get rid of `Select` and `Activate`:

```
Private Sub butSaveData_Click()

    With Sheet1
        With .Range("G8")
            .Value = txtAARs.Value
            .NumberFormat = "0.00"
        End With
    End With
```

Comment: That worked perfectly to change the text format to number format, thank you. For some reason the =sum() function still isn't working properly however. Perhaps I need to post a new question?

Comment: @BombSquad Yes, if the `SUM` isn't working even after all the values are numeric, that is definitely a different question.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. I'll post a fresh question if I cannot figure it out.